# MapReduce solution in python to identify asymmetric pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapreduce

I am attempting to write a Mapper and Reducer in Python, a language I am new to, that will print asymmetric key value pairs. For example:
Input

```
A,B
B,A
C,B
B,C
D,E
E,F
F,E
D,B
```

Output

```
D,E
D,B
```

Comment: So you know how to decompose the problem into the correct mapper and reducer, but you just need help with writing the two algorithms in Python?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've attempted anything.

Comment: Come on, this is a homework question from Introduction to Data Science from UWashington on Coursera.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pairs = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'F'), ('F', 'E'), ('D', 'B')]
>>> [k for k, c in Counter(map(frozenset, pairs)).items() if c == 1]
[frozenset(['B', 'D']), frozenset(['E', 'D'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two emits to the mapper.

```
def mapper(record):
    key = record[0]
    value = record[1]
    mr.emit_intermediate(key, value)
    mr.emit_intermediate(value, key)

def reducer(key, list_of_values):
    for n in list_of_values:
        if list_of_values.count(n) < 2:        
            output = key, n
            mr.emit((output))
```